# How to use messaging (Amazon SQS) in web api to return created id to the client

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-sqs, microservices

Just starting to use Amazon SQS service, so just wondering if someone can guide me into the right direction.
In case I have rest web-api interface exposed to the clients and after each http request I want to send asynchronous message to my separate service, which is responsible to create specific entity in the database and process with some logic. Something like this:

```
        var auctionRegistrationCommand = AuctionRegistrationCommand
            .CreateFromRequest(lotId, request);

        //var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient();
        //var response = sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(..resitrationCommaon..);
```

After entity is created I want to return Id of created entity to my client, so it can use it to update it or make some additional call to rest api. But I cannot find how to do it. Are there any patterns or approaches how to support such scenarios? Will be perfect to see some example using Amazon SQS, but general explanation will be also really helpful.

Comment: the first part is a use case of SQS, the second part is more a use case of SNS. One easy way would be to have the client poll for the status.

Comment: When using one way messaging, you should avoid synchronous communication. The client should be generating the id (using a guid) and the back end can then use it to create your record. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your two systems are S1 and S2, where the following happens:

1. S1 sends a message to SQS. This step is asynchronous.
2. S2 creates the required entity.
3. S1 is expected to notify caller of the newly created entity id.

#3 is not straightforward, given the very nature of asynchronous systems. For e.g., you don't know when S2 will process your request.

Possible solution:

1. S1 sends a message to SQS. SQS returns a `MessageId` in response. You return this `MessageId` to client.
2. Both S1 and S2 have a shared data store (for e.g., Memcache, MySQL etc.) which stores mapping of `MessageId` to entity-id. Whenever S2 process a message and creates a new entity, it updates this mapping in the shared data store.
3. Clients poll S1 with `MessageId`. S1 returns mapping from data store whenever it is non-null.

Documentation for `MessageId` from SQS's SendMessage API can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html).